# Command Prompt invoked by Runtime.getRuntime().exec() returning and printing "Not Enough memory resources are available to process this command"

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am invoking the API Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString(), envp, new File(workingDirStr));

I am not sure why the command prompt keeps printing the message "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command."

cmd /c start "" "script.bat"

^ That is roughly how the command starts. That batch files calls of to another script and starts a java process. Any ideas how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a windows issue

> *From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4339170/not-enough-memory-resources-error-cmd-winpe-windows-10*
>
> This issue occurs because a resource file is not included in the components that are responsible for keeping these copyright strings. As a result, when the command prompt tries to read the string, it cannot find the string, and it assumes the reason that the string was not found is a low-memory condition.